# Unity3D - Object edge color go Blue when put infront shader water object

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, game-development

Sorry because I capture the image from my phone because if I use a screenshot we will not see the blue edges.

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cq2CoHVDxSQ) to make an ocean in my game. If I look at a pink cube with the sea behind, it makes the pink cube edge color go Blue when the camera is moving.

Does anyone know what caused this please help,

Cheers,

[Photo 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwtC1.jpg)
[Photo 02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8d2T.jpg)

Comment: Pink texture is sign of shader compilation error. Please post your shader code.

Comment: I mean the cube has pink color, and the shader is on the ocean, the thing is when the camera moving there is a blue blur edge around the pink cube (only happens if the ocean is behind pink cube object) 
here the file if u want to take a look: https://github.com/Flaroon/Video-Files/tree/main/Shader%20Graph